# how to monitor text style and format in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text-editor, addeventlistener, execcommand

I have this text editor [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ifVF9K2dKmw7EJW1IwA8?p=preview) the problem is when I click the bold button or any other button the button doesn't show the state of the editable div, I know that could be fixed if I added a class to the button in the ng-mousedown event's function but that won't fix the problem if I click in an area with bold text that should add a class too to the correct toolbar button, maybe I should use somthing like a watcher but to watch what?

## Update

OK, I did some digging, I'm trying to watch the position of the caret so I can apply the correct style to a toolbar buttons of a text editor I thought about $watchers but I never used them.
The example that i'm using is from this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022) there's a Jsfiddle in the post but I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zFmun3AaVXxUtkwYDvyw?p=preview) example with AngularJS that shows how to get the caret position in the contenteditable div.
Is there a better way of doing this like get the DOM tree of the inner contenteditable div then make a map of elements and positions then use the data binding to control the state of the buttons in the toolbar?
Any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: that's a really long sentence...

Comment: Just updated my question.

Comment: why not use a well developed editor that has already been debugged and is cross browser compatiblie. Seems  like a big undertaking to re-invent the wheel

Comment: I need an editor with a toolbar not attached to it, or an editor with an API that i can use to control the editor through Javascript witch I couldn't find. maybe there's but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000543/895491):

> Rather than do all this by hand, the browser has methods to tell you if the current selection or caret is bold, italic or whatever: `document.queryCommandState()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), for binary commands such as a bold and italic, and `document.queryCommandValue()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) for commands with a value, such as font-related commands.

Comment: These are deprecated and non-standard!

Comment: you should not mark really old post like this as deprecated, the deprecation happen after the post.

Comment: the deprecation really happened afterwards, but it happened, so a user coming to this post could know that the accepted answer has deprecation. There is no other way to deal with software versions in stack.